# How can I test my Unity Touch Controls on Computer?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game in Unity for Android. The problem is, I use Iphone, so I can't check it connecting my phone with the computer, can I? But can I simulate a Android phone somehow on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect even an iphone in a Windows pc, you can simply connect it with iTunes downloaded and accept every condition while you plug it. After that, on Unity you can find on edit/preferences/external devices your phone and if you download the unity app and press play it should start on the phone.